# Replace Log4j library in maven pom file

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, log4j

We use ElasticSearch for our application. By a dependency in the pom file, we pull it in, do some configuration, and then repack it as a zip.
This is the defined dependency in the maven pom file.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.distribution.zip</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>${elasticsearch-version}</version>
        <type>zip</type>
</dependency>
```

The problem is that this zip contains 2 libraries that should be replaced.

- elasticsearch/lib/log4j-api-2.11.1.jar
- elasticsearch/lib/log4j-core-2.11.1.jar

The 2.17.0 jars should replace them.
I thought to exclude the dependencies to the old one in maven and package the new ones into the ElasticSearch zip. But when I add an exclude to the dependence, the jars are still available in the packaged zip. So this is what I tried to remove:

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The part where you show what you tried is missing. Would be good to see how the repackaging works, since that is where you should exclude/remove the log4j jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.elasticsearch.distribution.zip/elasticsearch/6.8.22/pom) does not specify any dependencies, the log4j jars are packaged in the elasticsearch artifact. So excluding dependencies will not work here. What you need to do is simply to remove/replace the files in between the unzipping and rezipping.